# RewriteCond not working in debian

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian

I have a PHP script running on apache server (debian). The problem is the "RewriteCond" doesn't seem to be working while `rewrite_mod` is enabled. Just a couple of instructions in the `.htaccess` are working, and this is why I'm encountering errors through the routing process and the server keeps saying that some routes haven't been found.

```
 IndexIgnore *
 Options -Indexes 

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^(config/|config\.php) - [F,L,NC]

 RewriteRule ^article/(.*)/? index.php?article&do=view&title=$1 [L,QSA] 
 RewriteRule ^thesis/(.*)/? index.php?thesis&do=view&title=$1 [L,QSA] 

 ====================================================
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} $
 RewriteCond     $1 !^(index)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/? index.php?$1&route=true [L,QSA]
 ==================================================== 

 RewriteRule ^me/? index.php?me [L,QSA] 

 RewriteRule ^home/? index.php?home [L,QSA] 



 RewriteRule    ^layout1.php index.php?layout1 [L,QSA]
```

For instance :

> domain/foo

It says foo not exist, But

> domain/home

is working with no errors

**EDIT :**

Now it got a portion of my problem working, I tried domain/FOO uppercase like thas and it seemed to work! Why is it to be working with uppercase? What can I do to get this to work in lowercase as well ? The foo.php is into the folder

Thank you

Comment: Is domain/me working?

Comment: I think your htaccess will work file if you reorder your rules by putting the conditional rules at botton and the bottom rules in middle.

Comment: @Starkeen Now it got a portion of my problem working, I tried domain/FOO uppercase like thas and it seemed to work!!! Why is it to be working with uppercase?? What can I do to get this to work in lowercase as well ? The foo.php is into the folder

Comment: @Starkeen I have already tested this, and chenged the location of rules and put them upside down, Didnt work then again